# rails error when db:migration add_rpx_to_admins after adding gem devise_rpx_connectable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rpx

The error :
/Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- devise/schema (LoadError)
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`block in require'
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise_rpx_connectable-0.2.2/lib/devise_rpx_connectable/schema.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in`load_dependency'
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise_rpx_connectable-0.2.2/lib/devise_rpx_connectable.rb:13:in`'
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`block in require'
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`require'
    from /Users/bo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /Users/bo/Rails/blog/config/application.rb:7:in`'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in`'

============================
My gems :
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.3)
  * actionpack (3.2.3)
  * activemodel (3.2.3)
  * activerecord (3.2.3)
  * activeresource (3.2.3)
  * activesupport (3.2.3)
  * arel (3.0.2)
  * bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
  * builder (3.0.0)
  * bundler (1.1.3)
  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
  * copycopter_client (2.0.0)
  * devise (2.1.0)
  * devise_rpx_connectable (0.2.2)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (1.3.2)
  * hike (1.2.1)
  * i18n (0.6.0)
  * journey (1.0.3)
  * jquery-datatables-rails (1.9.1.3 9e88f3c)
  * jquery-rails (2.0.2)
  * jquery-ui-rails (0.4.0)
  * json (1.7.3)
  * json_pure (1.7.3)
  * mail (2.4.4)
  * mime-types (1.18)
  * multi_json (1.3.5)
  * orm_adapter (0.0.7)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * rack (1.4.1)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.1)
  * rails (3.2.3)
  * railties (3.2.3)
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
  * rdoc (3.12)
  * rpx_now (0.6.24)
  * sass (3.1.18)
  * sass-rails (3.2.5)
  * sprockets (2.1.3)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.6)
  * thor (0.14.6)
  * tilt (1.3.3)
  * treetop (1.4.10)
  * tzinfo (0.3.33)
  * uglifier (1.2.4)
  * warden (1.1.1)

Thank you!